# Spring boot unit junit testing not loading configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to unit test Spring Boot Application. As a part of `main` method, I'm invoking `init` method in `Configuration` service to do some data setup . `Configuration` service is autowired in `Description` service.  When I try to unit test `Description` service, NPE is thrown as `init` method is not invoked in `Configuration` service. How to fix this.

BatchService:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.test.poc")
public class BatchService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(BatchService.class);
        try{
            context =  application.run();
            //Initialize
            Configuration config = (Configuration)context.getBean("Configuration");
            config.init();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ConfigurationService:

```
@Service
public class Configuration {
    private ConfigValue value = null;
    public void init(){
        //
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value.getNameValue();
   }
}
```

DescriptionService:

```
@Service
public class DescriptionService {

    @Autowired Configuration config;

    public List<String> getDescription(){
        String value = config.getValue();
    }
}
```

AbstractAutonomicsTest:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BatchService.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public abstract class AbstractAutonomicsTest {

}
```

DescriptionClusteringServiceTest:

```
public class DescriptionClusteringServiceTest extends AbstractAutonomicsTest  {

    @Autowired DescriptionClusteringService descService;

    @Test
    public void testDescription(){
        List<String> out = descService.getDescription();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the method yourself, let the framework do it for you. Just annotate the `init` method with `@PostConstruct` to have it invoked after the dependencies have been injected.

```
@Service
public class Configuration {
    private ConfigValue value = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value.getNameValue();
   }
}
```

Now you can also cleanup your `BatchService`. Note I suggest using `@SpringBootApplication` instead of 3 seperate annotations  and if your `BatchService` is in the `com.test.poc` package (or a super package) you can remove the `scanBasePackage` or value from `@ComponentScan`.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.test.poc").
public class BatchService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchService.class, args);
    }
}
```